# Edit a Parent Class from a Child Form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes, nested-resources

Currently, I am able to create multiple Students through my Adult Form by using       accepts_nested_attributes_for :student.

**But how can I Edit an existing Adult through a Student Form? (So the Opposite, except Edit)**

Currently I am able to create more Parents through my Student form, but thats not what I want.

**MODELS**

```
class Adult < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :students
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student
end


class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :adult
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :adult
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @adult = Adult.find(params[:adult_id])
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    if @student.update_attributes(student_params)
      redirect_to path
    end
  end

    private

    def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(:adult_id, :school_id, :username, :password, 
                                  :firstName, :middleName, :lastName, :alias,
                                  adult_attributes: [:id, :name])
    end 

end
```

**VIEWS**

```
###HOW CAN I UPDATE THE EXISTING PARENT AS OPPOSE TO CREATING ONE

<%= simple_form_for @student.build_adult do |f| %>
      <h4>Update Parent Information</h4>


      <%= f.label :firstName, 'First Name' %>
      <%= f.text_field :firstName, placeholder: "Parent's First Name", :class => "form-control"%>

      <%= f.submit "Save & Continue", class: "btn btn-primary"%>

<% end %>
```

**ROUTES**

```
resources :adult do
  resources :student
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,it is `has_many :students`,so it should be `accepts_nested_attributes_for :students` not `accepts_nested_attributes_for :student`.

Secondly,if i understood your question correctly,you are trying to `update` the existing `parent(adult) record` but you are ending up creating a new one.Is that the problem? If so,you need to permit the `:id of the student` for which the parent(adult) record need to be updated.

Change your `student_params` method to like this

```
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:id,:adult_id, :school_id, :username, :password, 
  :firstName, :middleName, :lastName,:alias,adult_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this solution, but it may work...

Try using `@parent.update_attributes` instead of creating a separate parent form, send the parent params with the student params. You may need to define a `parent_params()` function to permit them.

** I believe the permit params will filter out the non-permitted ones, so you won't need to specify only the student or parents fields for their respect `update_attributes`.